# android image-view across or beyond the layout

Tags: android, android-layout

In android can we set the image-view having two layouts i mean the image need to be set at end of the edge and occupying other layout also unlike overlay

any possibilities

[image]

in this image the pin icon is designed like going out the layout, any idea please

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can overlap the images using RelativeLayout

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html